# Rails 5: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to load CSV data and provide it to my view as JSON.

I have the following file:
`app/assets/csvs/nodes.csv`

And the following in `config/initializers/assets.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "csvs")
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( nodes.csv )
```

And the following in my controller

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'
csv = Rails.root + ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('nodes.csv')
csv_data = File.read(csv)
@data = CSV.parse(csv_data).to_json
```

I get this error in the view

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /assets/nodes-0ae0ea48564414179cf3ee3ebcd4e6471c74eabd054d20060762d471ba8d6e80.csv
```

If I go to:

`http://localhost:3000/assets/nodes-0ae0ea48564414179cf3ee3ebcd4e6471c74eabd054d20060762d471ba8d6e80.csv`

I see the contents of the .csv

I've tried

`csv = Rails.root + ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('nodes.csv')`

with and without `Rails.root` and no joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do something like this:

```
path = "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/csvs/nodes.csv"
file = File.open(path, 'r')
rows = CSV.parse(file, headers: true)
@data = rows.to_json
```

Try it and let me know how is going.

Comment: Thanks! This helped! I ended up using `path = "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/csvs/nodes.csv"
    file = File.read(path)
    csv = CSV.new(file, :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol, :converters => :all)
    @data = csv.to_a.map {|row| row.to_hash }`

Comment: I am glad! Mark as the answer if you think my answer was good :)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your error message, rails is looking in the `assests/` dir and not the `assets/csvs` dir.

Try

```
csv = ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('csvs/nodes.csv')
```

Or you could just put the `.csv` in the `assets/` dir directly.

Note you will never need to prepend `Rails.root +`

Comment: I tried both suggestions, `asset_path('csvs/nodes.csv')` and got an error "No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /csvs/nodes.csv" and then I tried putting nodes.csv in the assets directory and using `asset_path('nodes.csv')` and got an error "No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /assets/nodes-0ae0ea48564414179cf3ee3ebcd4e6471c74eabd054d20060762d471ba8d6e80.csv"